# Calculate cumulative sum across static axis in CNTK

Tags: python, deep-learning, cntk

I'd like to calculate the cumulative sum of a tensor in a CNTK model. This is reasonably straightforward to do for sequences, but it's unclear how to do this on static axes. If one knows the dimensionality of the axis a priori you could conceivably do this with a convoluted set of gather/reduce_sum/splice operations, but this would be ridiculously inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operations like that are definitely on our todo list. Since this can be expessed as a matrix product, it won't be too inefficient with the following implementation:

```
def cumsum(x, axis=-1):
   d = x.shape[axis]
   U = C.constant(np.triu(np.ones((d,d))).astype(x.dtype))
   if axis != -1:
      x = C.swapaxes(x, -1, axis)
   z = C.times(x, U)
   if axis != -1:
      z = C.swapaxes(z, -1, axis)
   return z
```